# How do you navigate a webpage in firefox using tab and keyboard?

Tags: firefox, navigation, keyboard, accessibility

On my mac, Firefox doesn't automatically navigate web pages in the same way as Chrome when using the tab key.

For example visit smashingmagazine.com In chrome pressing the tab key focuses on a skip to main content button and then cycles through the nav. In Firefox, pressing the tab key focuses on a random link.

**Chrome**
[image]

**Firefox**
[image]

How can I do keyboard navigation using tab in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, inputs and buttons receive focus but links don't.

In *System Preferences → Keyboard*, in the *Shortcuts* pane, you’ll have either a “All controls” radio or a “Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls” checkbox, depending on your MacOS version.

Check this (you may need to restart Firefox) and Firefox should now behave more like Chrome.